Higher dimensional Goursat theorem and Cauchy theorem possible?
This might not be a proper question. But I will try my best to present my ideas.
If $A$ is a real unital Banach algebra with finite dimension ($>1$), but not necessarily a division algebra. If a functions $f: A\to A$ has Frechet derivative in an open region $U\subset A$, this seems to be a higher dimensional equivalent to a complex function being holomorphic. Then, we can define $A$ integral $\int_{M^{n-1}}f(w)dw$ on a smooth compact manifold of $n-1$ dimension, where $f(w)$ and $dw$ are multiplied through the algebra multiplication of $A$, mirroring how the complex line integral is defined. Then, using the argument of splitting $n-1$ simplex into $2^n$ parts of equal volume, it seems we can prove a higher dimensional version of Goursat theorem, and therefore a higher dimensional Cauchy theorem. We just need to be careful and avoid topologically complicated $n-1$ dimensional manifolds to take the integrals on.
I can't seem to convince myself why the above thoughts are nonsense. But when learning complex analysis, the fact that it's true $i^2=-1$ in the complex field was nearly all the focus was put on. But if my above paragraph contains no nonsense, that would mean the reason why holomorphic functions are so nice has nothing to do with the algebraic completeness of $\mathbb{C}$, and only due to the fact it has a dimension higher than 1. Whether it is a division algebra or not isn't even relevant either.
(Also, we can define exponential function $exp: A\to A$ as usual, but we might not have a nice higher dim version of the polar decomposition $z=re^{i\theta}$ as in the complex case. So identity $\int_C 1/z dz=2\pi i$ might not generalize nicely either. Whence, when we restrict to the open set of invertible elements, Cauchy Integral Formulas (hence Liouvulle's theorem, and everything based on CIF) might fail. )
So the question is: how wrong is my paragraph above? If wrong, how? Thanks in advance.
Update. I realized only requiring $f$ having Frechet derivative is not equivalent to the requirement of being holomorphic. When $A=\mathbb{C}$, being holomorphic is stronger because $A$ has a very nice matrix representation. So to properly mimic the complex case, we need to assume the regular representation $\rho: A\to \mathcal{B}(A)$ is nice enough. I'll try to work out the details.
Update2. Turns out we only need to require $f: A\to A$ to be left/right $A$-linearly differentiable: there exists a left/right homomorphism $h: A\to A$ s.t. $f(w+z)-f(w)=h(z)+\mathcal{O}(\|z\|)$. Then there is no issue mimicking the complex case. Just need to be careful with left/right-ness.

If $A$ is 1-dimensional, there are only two directions you can take for the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$: either $x\to x_0^+$ or $x\to x_0^-$. For any higher dimension, there are suddenly infinitely many paths from which you can take the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$, so $f$ having a derivative at $x_0$ becomes a much stronger property. This is how I see the rigidity of holomorphic functions, and it makes sense that this rigidity should increase as the dimension increases, so I’d bet one can do better than just an analogue of Goursat. Nice question (+1)

I've only quickly skimmed your post, but have you already ready about the standard generalization of Cauchy's Integral Theorem to higher dimensions on, say, Wikipedia? Is that not satisfying/significantly different from your aim here?

@MarkS. Thanks for the link. It seems they are talking about a more special situation involving vector fields. I'll have to read it more carefully and see

@MarkS. But the point of distinguishing complex analysis as a subject of its own, is exactly to avoid relying on Green's theorem. So in higher dimensional situation, the point should also be to avoid relying on Stoke's theorem. So I guess what they mention there is not really the line of logic I'm after. But the results coincide

There is a kind of higher dimensional residue theorem discussed in Iversen's book on sheaf cohomology

regarding your update: when $A=\Bbb{C}$, holomorphy is equivalent to having a $\Bbb{C}$-linear Frechet derivative (whereas $\Bbb{R}^2$-differentiability only has an $\Bbb{R}$-linear Frechet derivative). But this is a nice question which I’ve thought about on and off, and each time I come back to the conclusion that the reason Goursat’s theorem works out is because in $\Bbb{C}$, we have the complex multiplication which allows us to consider the 1-form $f(z),dz$ and integrate it along curves. I haven’t pinpointed the precise generalization so far. (+1 :)

having said this, I don’t think focusing on a Banach algebra and maps $f:A\to A$ is the ‘right’ generalization because in complex analysis, even if we have two arbitrary complex Banach spaces $V,W$ and an open set $\Omega\subset V$, then once complex Frechet differentiability (i.e holomorphy) of $f:\Omega\to W$ is equivalent to infinitely often complex Frechet differentiability is equivalent to being analytic (having a suitable ‘power series’ expansion about each point (this needs to be carefully when $V\neq\Bbb{C}^n$))

@peek-a-boo Thanks for the comment. I updated again :) Perhaps now it works out.

@peek-a-boo I think in the higher dim case, due to the algebra multiplication, 1-form $f(w)dw$ still makes sense, so long as $M^{n-1}$ is sufficiently nice: piece-wise smooth and its inside being contractible.

Oh that reminds me, the integration doesn’t make sense because the dimensions don’t match; you’d need to integrate an $(n-1)$-form, not a $1$-form.

@peek-a-boo What if, for every compact smooth manifold $M^k$, we do $f(w) \cdot_A dw:= \sum_{i=1}^k d_1w \wedge \cdots \wedge \left(f(w)\cdot_A d_i w\right)\wedge\cdots \wedge d_kw$?

what do you even mean by $d_iw$?

@peek-a-boo you are right. Something doesn't add up

@peek-a-boo When writing that reply, I was hoping $$f(w) \cdot_A dw:= \sum_{i=1}^k dw^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \left(f(w)\cdot_A d w^i\right)\wedge\cdots \wedge dw^k$$ would work. Sorry about botching the index. But then I realized such a thing may not be coordinate-invariant, and so not well-defined on $M^k$.
Then I recall, complex contour integral is actually a Riemann-Stieltjets integral. So I'm thinking maybe on higher dimensions, we must do a higher-dim version of Riemann-Stieltjets. Still trying to figure that out

@peek-a-boo Or maybe we just restrict to integral on the curves regardless of the dimension.
